# Is there any way to batch export TLS States with additional files?

Tags: traffic, sumo

From https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/Traffic_Lights.html#tls_states , I know that I can use command `<timedEvent type="SaveTLSStates" source="<TLS_ID>" dest="<OUTPUT_FILE>"/>` in additional file to output the state of the traffic light, whose ID is "TLS_ID" defined in `.net.xml file`. However I wonder that if I use this way to output the TLS, do I have to enter this command for each ID of the traffic light? Is there a statement that can output the state of all traffic light defined in `.net.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can write a small python script to achieve that:

```
import sumolib

net = sumolib.net.readNet("net.net.xml")
states_xml = sumolib.xml.create_document("additional")
for tls in net.getTrafficLights():
    event = states_xml.addChild("timedEvent")
    event.setAttribute("type", "SaveTLSStates")
    event.setAttribute("source", tls.getID())
    event.setAttribute("dest", "states.xml")
with open("output.add.xml", 'w') as out:
    out.write(states_xml.toXML())
```

Please be aware that I did not test the code above.